# Remove headers from automatic GET to the 303 redirect on Location

Tags: javascript, http, axios

I have a secured endpoint (`POST`) that requires an `Authorization` header. This endpoint can return a 303 redirect with a `Location` header that contains a valid url to be retrieved via a `GET`.

Problem is, the `Authorization` header is only needed and accepted by the original URL however it is automatically passed along by the browser in the `GET` request to the the `303 Location` endpoint. How can I stop this `Authorization` header from being passed along in the redirect?

Comment: Is the location you're redirecting to on a different or the same domain?

Comment: @Evert Different domain, Azure blob storage

Comment: I imagine that this must be an Axios security bug then, and quite a big one.

Comment: @Evert, let me do this with jquery and see what happens. I figured it was the browser doing this or something. This request doesn't even fall into the `.then` function before or after the 303 response and redirect.

Comment: This still happens with Jquery as well. CORS is wide open on the Azure blob.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to strip that property off of your headers on the server side, you can strip that in your POST route. You could do this in your POST route or other middleware that you create. I'm not sure what you're using on the server side, but if you're using express, you can modify the req.headers object, delete the property, or set it to whatever you'd like. Give it a try and let me know if that works for you. Here's an example of how that might look.

```
app.post('/your_route', (req, res, next) => {
  //whatever you're doing with your request here
  delete req.headers['header-name'];
  //your redirect here

});
```

The code example isn't perfect but it's worth a try!